# Canvas opaque - change default background color

Tags: javascript, android, html, animation, canvas

I'm using `canvas.getContext('2d', {alpha: false});` ([wiki info](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/CanvasOpaque)) to remove canvas opacity and improve performance of animation. Unfortunately after that, canvas element gain white background. Is there an option to change the default color of canvas background/color?

I tried `drawImage()` to fill whole area, but (because of animation) I think it is not the best solution:

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('#mycanvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d', {alpha: false});

function run() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height);

    ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, size.width, size.height);

    draw();
    update();

    requestAnimationFrame(run);
}
```

I really care about performance, so it would be useful to change the color only once.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

No. The default background is always black.

> The CanvasRenderingContext2D.clearRect() method of the Canvas 2D API
>   sets all pixels in the rectangle defined by starting point (x, y) and
>   size (width, height) to transparent black, erasing any previously
>   drawn content.

Instead of clearing the canvas, just set fillRect to fill with the color you want.

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('#mycanvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d', {alpha: false});

function run() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height);

    draw();
    update();

    requestAnimationFrame(run);
}
```

Comment: @Amay Then you're doing something wrong. Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rrubqon6/

Comment: No. This example is not an animation with clearRect();

Comment: Nice update but still not good idea - fillStyle() with fillRect() is slower than drawImage().